# Populate a DataGridView correctly

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm writing a winforms application, with a datagrid, using some search field to filter the content of the dataGrid.

To fill my dataGrid, I load data using a query.

The result of the query is either a `DataTable`, or a `List<Object>` created with the dataTable.

I read that to use search field, I had to populate my dataGrid like this :

```
    liste = Echange.GetListEchange(contextExecution.ChaineConnexion, criteres);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = liste;
```

And building the query like this :

```
" AND UPPER(titre) like '%" + tbSearchTitre.Text.ToUpper() + "%' AND ";
```

Then adding as parameter in GetListEchange.

This works.

I got columns, binding of properties on the `liste` .

But the thing is, I got aside, a Select column (CheckBoxColumn) binding on a property.
And when I set the property to true, then, the checkBox should check, but nothing happened.

```
    foreach (Echange itm in liste)
    {
        itm.IsSelect = false;
    }
```

It seems the dataGrid don't update.

But when I go through all the `Echange` in the liste, and I checked 'graphically' the checkbox, then, IsSelect is true.

So why, when I set IsSelect to true, the checkBox is not checked?

Is there a better way to fill my dataGrid, using search fields, and that update the display of the dataGrid?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are not using the `CheckBox`properties properly. I've went through all properties here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox_properties%28v=vs.100%29.aspx and I haven't found `IsSelect`. Is it a custom property? In order to check/uncheck checkbox you should use `item.Checked = true/false`.

Comment: Yes it is a custom property, that I bind in the column. I don't have `Checked`property on my item. Just the propery I define in my `Echange`class.